# wish list count using ajax

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, wishlist

I'm using ajax wishlist to add product in wishlist everything work fine but i can't update the wishlist count in header using ajax here is the **php** script that i called using ajax to get the current quantity in wishlist

```
       <?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
 $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer, true);

echo $wishlist->getItemsCount();
}
```

but this give me a 500 internal server error in console

Comment: Try this. `echo $wishlist->getItemsCount();`

Comment: Also after `Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));` defining this you can use `$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");` . No need to use `array('name'=>'frontend')` again.

Comment: @Kingshuk Deb Please see my updated code still have the same internal error

Comment: In which folder you are running this code?

Comment: @Kingshuk Deb Inside the skin folder "/skin/frontend/qbid/qbd/js/ajaxwishlist/wishcount.php where the whislist add js is on same folder

Comment: You should really talk to Magento using Controller-classes. Then it's actually easy to stay in the same session. Here is a short introduction: http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world/